# How to import git package into spark kernel in AWS Sagemaker notebook

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, scala, jupyter-notebook

I want to import and use this scala git package (https://github.com/seratch/AWScala) on AWS sagemarker notebook script to call AWS APIS. I tried cloning this package through the notebook terminal, but the import didn't work.

1. I'm not sure how Jupyter notebook supports a scala package and how to add this dependency into the script.
2. Is there other AWS SDKs for scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Almond](https://almond.sh/) as your Jupyter kernel, then it supports [Ammonite way of importing things](https://ammonite.io/#MagicImports). So running:

```
import $ivy.`com.github.seratch::awscala:0.8.4`
// now you can import library's packages
```

should do the trick.

If you have some other Scala kernel, then similar thing should be mentioned in its documentation.

Scala runs on JVM so you can always use [Java AWS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java) from Scala if this library isn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks! Can Java AWS SDK run in the Jupyter notebook? Do I need to install java kernel to do that?

Comment: No, you don't have to. Scala can use Java libraries natively. You would need to install Java kernel if you wanted to use Java's syntax. As long as you call these libraries from Scala, Almond is enough.